# Changing the color of rows in a DataGrid in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am having problems changing the color of the DataGrid rows, I use the following function

```
int i = 0;
private void gvDados_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridRow rowContext = e.Row;
   if (rowContext != null)
   {
      string Situacao = dt.Rows[i]["Situacao"].ToString();
      if (Situacao.Equals("V"))
      {
         SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 104,0));
         rowContext.Background = brush;
      }
      else
      {
         SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 232,0));
         rowContext.Background = brush;
      }

      i++;
   }
}
```

So far so good, I can adjust the colors according to what I want, the problem in question is when I use the Horizontal Scroll Bar to go down the registers or climb, then all colors are misconfigured appearing at random. How can I solve this problem so things do not change when scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LoadingRow` event of `DataGrid` fires whenever a `Row` is 'instantiated'. When you scroll rows go in and out of scope, and this event is fired repeatedly for each row that 'loads' into the view.

Assuming that your `DataGrid` is loaded at some event such as a button click or some such action, you probably need to do the coloring of rows when you actually load the data into your `DataGrid`, preferably using a function written for that, and later on call the function again if content is changed and you want to display colors according to changed content.

Something like this:

```
// This could be a button event, or some other event after which you load data into the DataGrid
void ButtonLoadEvent()
{
    foreach(Datagrid Row)
    {
        FunctionThatChangesRowColor(Row);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Actual code on how to get DataGrid rows and apply coloring. This is a modified version of your coloring logic, and here each row is colored depending on whether its row index is odd or even. You may replace this with your code.

Pass the entire `DataGrid` to this function.

```
private void ColorRow(DataGrid dg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

        if (row != null)
        {
            int index = row.GetIndex();
            if (index % 2 == 0)
            {
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 104, 0));
                row.Background = brush;
            }
            else
            {
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 232, 0));
                row.Background = brush;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But that too is not a perfect solution seeing as you're using WPF, not WinForms. One suggestion I have is to go for a WPF DataBinding approach, and let the XAML do the color coding for you.

[This](https://gist.github.com/sachintha81/df04102801733cdd6a245c77a86c474b) is a sample of code that I often use for this purpose.

**WPF Approach Code:**

```
<Window x:Class="ColorLibrary.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColorLibrary"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Code}"></Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <!-- Stuff -->

        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Name="dgvColors"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Margin="4">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="#" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Num}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="HTML Code" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In,

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Code}"></Setter>
```

`Code` is a property in a class which contains the color name to be used to color the cell.

Then we have an `ObservableCollection` of that class objects. You need to set this property (of each item in the `ObservableCollection`) to the color you need each row to be displayed in.

Comment: I need to do this programmatically how do I read each row in the datagrid and change its color? using a while and according to my condition changing the color

Comment: The WPF approach _is_ doing it programmatically. You just let XAML do the coloring instead of doing it in code behind. But if you must use code behind, see the update I've posted. Use a `foreach` loop on the `DataGrid` rows and pass rows to the function that colors them.

Comment: An error occurs when using the foreach (DataGridRow Row in gvData)
  {myfunction ()}

Comment: That's just pseudocode. Let me update with an example on how to get each row.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I found other examples, but it is not quite what I needed but this is perfect.

Comment: Did you test this example? I run here and when I send my datagrid and it gets the row all goes like null, even I try to set the itemssources

Comment: Yes I did run it; hence the different `if` condition so that I could verify it works. As long as you pass a datagrid that has rows, this should work.

Comment: It contains rows and even then all the rows that is received from the DataGrid come as null, and debugging I saw that the DataGrid has 23 rows

Comment: Perhaps you're passing the DataGrid before it is populated.

Comment: `Search();`
`AtualizaCores(gvDados);`
`gvDados.UpdateLayout();`
        `public void Search() {`
          `  dt = Controller.ListAll();`
          `  gvDados.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;`
       ` } `

Comment: @Sach, why do you have double quotes around attribute values (like `""500""`)? it is not valid xaml, is it? it is the first time I see such markup, I'm curious

Comment: @ASh yes that is invalid syntax, must have been an error while copying or something. Thanks for pointing out, will fix right away!